# How can GRUB access initramfs file if its stored in RAID

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, raid

I am reading about how boot process in Linux works and just cannot understand one thing:

If `GRUB` is the one who copies `initramfs` into memory and only after that `init` process starts (which is then responsible for loading Kernel modules required to support i.e. `RAID`). Then can `GRUB` find `initramfs` image if it is stored on a disk which is actually a part of `RAID` (no drivers loaded yet)? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

GRUB obviously needs, and uses, drivers in order to access files stored on a RAID. For example if you use a `mdadm` software RAID, you will see `insmod mdraid09` in your `grub.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but there still remains the question - how? How can `GRUB` access `RAID` drivers which are stored (probably) on `RAID`?

Comment: What sort of RAID are we talking about, anyway?

Comment: Let's say some hardware RAID controller i.e. based on Intel chipsets